# How can I replace null value with n/a in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js, chartkick

I am working on dynamic chart created through chartkick and chart.js in rails.

[image: data shown from console that consists of null data].

The data got null is not the problem. The problem is that I want to display null/empty to n/a.

My chart looks like:

[image: chart]

To solve this, I first update the database through the code mention below:

```
Roster.where(caste_group: "").update_all(caste_group:"n/a")
```

But this is exactly not what I wanted. Everytime updating the database is not efficient.
Then I used transform key helper. The code goes as

```
    caste_group = Roster.group(:caste_group).count
   @caste_group = caste_group.transform_keys{ |key| key==""? 
   "n/a":key }
```

Here `Roster` is the model which consist of following attribute caste_group as string and user select caste_group as dropdown.
Using this transform key helper I got the result which doesn't display null value. null/empty value isn't rename to n/a.
And my code in a view goes as

```
 = line_chart @event_chart,discrete:true, legend: "bottom",curve: false,
           colors: ["#67b55e","#d43766","#729be0"]
```

Comment: What exactly is a **null** value? You are testing whether `key` is an empty string.

Comment: @user1934428 yes the key is an empty string. I want to change empty string to n/a

Comment: The code is reasonable, though I would (for safety) replace it by `key.empty`, so that you get an exception if, by some programming error, the key happens to be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this at many levels, so depends on what you need.
One way to solve this would be to set a default value in the database. So every time your model is saved with null it will actually be saved as "n\a".

You can run a migration like so:

```
change_column_default :rosters, :caste_group, "n\a"
```

But maybe you don't want to edit all the data in the DB. In that case, you can do it at the model or presenter level. I think the code you posted from the helper is all right. Are you not satisfied with it?

Comment: I don't want to change the database. I just want to change the display of the view only i.e my chart. If the change the database the whole project will be mess. So I don't want to do it. The sad point is I am not getting the result through transform_keys. @Alexander

Answer (score 1):

If your query can return null, and "", e.g

```
Roster.group(:caste_group).count
{
  nil=>12,
  ''=>123,
  'name_first'=>2
}
```

This can help

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN caste_group IS NULL
    THEN 'n/a'
    WHEN caste_group=''
    THEN 'n/a'
    ELSE caste_group
    END AS caste_group,
    count(*)
  FROM rosters
  GROUP BY 1
SQL
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

This will compile NULL or '' to 'n/a'.

example result:

```
[
  {"caste_group"=>"n/a", "count"=>"1"},
  {"caste_group"=>"name_first", "count"=>"2"}
]
```

Next you can transform this in needed hash.

```
result.each_with_object({}) { |caste_group, res| res[caste_group['caste_group']] = caste_group['count'] }
```

e.g

```
{"n/a"=>"1", "name_first"=>"2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thankfully solves this.
The problem with mine is that I have already updated the database to "n/a". So, when I change the key through transform_keys I am facing the problem.
After that I rename n/a to "N/A" and solves for me.

```
   caste_group = Roster.group(:caste_group).count
@caste_group = caste_group.transform_keys{ |key| key==""? "N/A":key }
```

I am posting the answer because it might be helpful for others in future.